# Moving chatbot in teams from one Azure subscription to other subscription

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

I have a Bot App deployed in MS Teams that is using a Azure Bot Service.My Team wants to move this bot  to a new Azure subscription with new resource group.But the issue is what will happen to the users who are already using the old App,once the subscription is terminated will they be asked to force uninstall the app or is there any other method so that the users can move to new app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anu, You can move your resources from one subscription to another subscription without any issue. Follow below steps

- Go to Resources groups
- Select your Resource group where your application is currently hosted
- In the next screen, search for your Subscription name. In the same line you will get the "Change" subscription option.
- After you click "Change", you will be redirected to the page where you can select resources you want to move and the destination subscription option.
- To validate your move from one subscription to another please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#validate-move) documentation.

Comment: getting error : Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined

Comment: i am getting below error when i am trying to move the resource group to other subscription,i am getting this error:{
  "message": "Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined\n    at c (https://portal.azure.com/AzureHubs/Content/Dynamic/BelzPLa-5LK8.js:2:668)\n    at o (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/uy7P2dwIDVkF.js:4:72)\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/uy7P2dwIDVkF.js:4:5594"
}